# Immutable classes fields queries

Tags: java, immutability, private, final

I have a few questions related to `immutable` class fields.

Suppose I have a class `Student`:

```
public class Student {

    private final int empId;
    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public Student(int empId) {
        this.empId=empId;

    }
}
```

Question 1: why its necessary to define the field as `private` final?

Question 2: Why `final` is required along with `private`. As when we declared the field as `final` it will not be visible outside the class?

Question 3: Why can't we make it `public final`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1: why its necessary to define field as private final?

Because otherwise there is a possibility to add code that modifies the field, and then it's not immutable anymore.

> Question 2: Why final is required along with private. As when we declared the field as final it will not be visible outside the class?

That last sentence is not true; making a field `final` does not make it invisible outside the class. Making it invisible outside the class is what the `private` keyword does.

> Question 3: Why can't we make it public final?

You can make it `public final`, but fields should normally be `private` and only be accessed directly by methods inside the class.

Comment: q1) not strictly true because a public final int is invulnerable to modification

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. For point 2 it was typing mistake I meant private. Question 2: Why final is required along with private. As when we declared the field as PRIVATE it will not be visible outside the class?

Comment: @KamalVerma `private` doesn't directly have anything to do with whether the class is immutable or not. The point about immutable is: it should not be possible to change the state (the member variables) after the object is constructed and initialized.

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1: why its necessary to define field as private final?

No, it it not.  `final` is enough for immutability.

> Question 3: Why can't we make it public final?

We can do it.
In your example `int empId` is out of the box immutable (as any primitive).
So making `empId` `public` or `private` will not change the state of Student while it is declared as final (that is no reassignable after instantiation of the class that contains it).

In a general way, providing fields with a `public` modifier is not advised as it defeats the encapsulation principle of OOP.

> Question 2: Why final is required along with private. As when we
>   declared the field as final it will not be visible outside the class?

No, the `final` modifier does only what it is described above but anyway as explained, in your case (primitive), making the field visible or not has no incidence on immutability of it while it is `final`.

Comment: "In a general way, providing fields with public modifier is not advised as it defeats the encapsulation principle mechanism" The getter is breaking encapsulation in just the same way

Comment: @Michael Yes the most of times. But it has a  difference : getting a value with a method is much flexible as it allows to use polymorphism, logic, validation, caching, etc... You cannot do it with field access.

Comment: A getter, by definition, breaks encapsulation all of the time. What you're *really* saying is that declaring it `public` is less flexible than providing a getter. Encapsulation is broken either way.

Comment: By definition ? But which definition do you refer to ? I understand your point but I think you generalize a little. Using dumb getters for all fields breaks in a some way the encapsulation but providing getters for fields where it is required is fine if the class API is designed to return some values.

Comment: Encapsulation is the principle of not exposing the data an object contains. Getters expose the data an object contains. I didn't say getters aren't *sometimes* necessary or *always* a terrible idea. I said it *always* breaks encapsulation.

Comment: @Michael And there you are downvoting for a side matter that has no core relation  with the question ? I give up discussing with haters...

Comment: Misleading ??? Wrong ??? **You** was **misleading** by commenting about "getters" that is not the matter of the question and not in my answer either. It is my last messagE.

Comment: @Michael: the mere existence of a `getEmpId()` method does not prove that the object contains a field `empId` that has been exposed. That value could have been calculated on the fly, for example. Since you could remove the field without the code using that object noticing, I’d call that encapsulation.

Comment: @Michael: ahem, all the time? What else do you mean with “Getters always break encapsulation”? I don’t see any way to interpret this as “getters *provide* (some degree of) encapsulation”.

Comment: @Michael: whether a method is a getter or just a method which returns a value, is exactly what has been encapsulated, as the only way to find out, is to look at its code.

Comment: @Holger I don't think you understand the difference between encapsulation and abstraction. Feel free to chat me but this comment section is ridiculous right now.